# How to count fields in a string?

Tags: python, string, validation, variables, field

I would like to know if there is a way to know if a string with parameter is valid and count how many fields there are inside. I would prefer a native Python function(s) but I did not find anything about it.
Let say that this function is called *count_variables*

I would have:

```
count_variables("Test") # -> 0

count_variables("Test {0} {1}") # -> 2

count_variables("Test {0} {2}") # -> raise error {1} is missing

count_variables("Test {} {}") # -> 2

count_variables("Test{ {} {}") # -> raise error { is not escaped

count_variables("Test {} {0}") # -> raise error cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field
```

I am using python 2.7

As @dot.Py has mentioned, a lighter function *is_valid* could be easier. Only the string validation without having required parameters

```
is_valid("Test") # -> True

is_valid("Test {0} {2}") # -> False

...
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you tried doing this yourself?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I think it is important not to reinvent the wheel. That's why I prefer to ask if it exists native methods. I mean the "format" method could raise an exception if I had parameters, but I don't. I have to validate without parameters. If it does not exist I will do it my self, but I can miss cases.

Comment: A really good way to avoid reinventing the wheel is to spend more time reading the documentation...

Comment: @martineau. I guess you can show me the documentation page for what I am looking for. 
As you apparently spend more time than me reading documentation.

Comment: Guess that must be true. [_Custom String Formatting_](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) might have been a good place to start—and another would be that of for the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) module. Of course this assumes one is able to combine existing tools when creating their own solutions (instead of just asking someone else to figure it out here instead of making any effort in doing so themselves).

Comment: interesting. You were here not to help, just to do bad criticizes, and you suggest to use the "re" lib for this kind of issue.You were the guy saying "A really good way to avoid reinventing the wheel  is to spend more time reading reading the documentation...". and you suggest to read the "re" documentation. Really funny. I advise you to read the "right" documentation it could help you on the future. Have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea is to use the `string.Formatter.parse` to count the variables and then to actually try formatting with exactly that many variables.

It works for the examples listed in the question, but otherwise is not very well tested.

```
import string

def vcount(fmt):
    try:
        cnt = sum(1 for text, name, spec, conv in string.Formatter().parse(fmt) if name is not None)
        fmt.format(*range(cnt))
    except Exception as err:
        print("error: {}".format(err))
        return None # or raise ValueError(err)
    print(cnt)
    return cnt 

vcount("Test") # -> 0
vcount("Test {0} {1}") # -> 2
vcount("Test {0} {2}") # -> raise error
vcount("Test {} {}") # -> 2
vcount("Test{ {} {}") # -> raise error
vcount("Test {} {0}") # -> raise error
```

---

UPDATE: a different approach, not equivalent to the original answer. See comments. The error message for invalid input might be confusing.

```
def vcount(fmt):
    try:
        names = [name for text, name, spec, conv in string.Formatter().parse(fmt) if name is not None]
        if all(name == "" for name in names):
            # unnumbered fields "{} {}"
            cnt = len(names)
        else:
            # numbered "{0} {1} {2} {0}"
            cnt = 1 + max(int(name) for name in names)
        fmt.format(*range(cnt))
    except Exception as err:
        print("error: {}".format(err))
        return None # or raise ValueError(err)
    print(cnt)
    return cnt
```

Comment: `fmt.format(*range(cnt))` is going to raise an error on non-numeric format specs.

Comment: True, but actually it was what I needed. :)

Comment: @VPfB It was a good idea, to use count and then use the format method. Good job ;)

Comment: Shorter than my solution and I learnt about `string.Formatter().parse()`. +1

Comment: An issue with this algo is 
`vcount("Test {0} {1} {0} ") # -> 3`

Comment: @M07 I am not sure what should be the correct answer in this case with duplicates. Your specification is not complete, it is given in form of test cases. So the returned number of fields in that string should be 2 or 3? Or an error should be raised? For example for this string `"Test {0} {2}"` you want an "missing field" exception, but someone else could expect resulting value of 3, beacuse `"Test {0} {2}".format(1, "unused2", 3)` is valid.

Comment: True. What I have in mind was to retrieve the amount of required fields for the `format` function.  I did not think about the case you mentioned. `"Test {0} {2}".format(1, "unused2", 3)``. I guess it should return 3, in that case. 
It was more complex than I expected.

Comment: @M07 Please take a look at the alternative I have appended to my answer.

Comment: @VPfB, That's good indeed. Would you just update your code to add `fmt.format(*range(cnt))`?

Comment: @M07 Yes, I will. It could catch "Test {-1}". Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a built-in way but I've implemented a solution myself. I've tested it under Python 3.5 and Python 2.7. It's "correct" insofar as it passes the test cases you've provided:

**Implementation**

```
import re
import unittest


class Numbering:
    NONE = 0
    MANUAL = 1
    AUTOMATIC = 2


def consecutive_variables(variables):
    sorted_variables = sorted(variables)
    return all(a == b - 1 for a, b in zip(sorted_variables[:-1], sorted_variables[1:]))


def count_variables(data):
    numbering = Numbering.NONE
    last_variable = 0
    variables = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        c = data[i]

        if c == '{':
            match = re.match(r'(\d|^{|^})*?(?=})', data[i + 1:])

            if not match:
                raise ValueError('Invalid variable formatting')

            variable_body = match.group(0)

            if variable_body == '':
                if numbering == Numbering.MANUAL:
                    raise ValueError('Cannot switch from manual to automatic numbering')

                numbering = Numbering.AUTOMATIC
                variables.append(last_variable)
                last_variable += 1
            else:
                if numbering == Numbering.AUTOMATIC:
                    raise ValueError('Cannot switch from automatic to manual numbering')

                numbering = Numbering.MANUAL
                variables.append(int(variable_body))

            i += len(variable_body) + 1
            assert data[i] == '}'

    if not consecutive_variables(variables):
        raise ValueError('Variables are not consecutive')

    return len(variables)
```

**Tests**

```
class TestCountVariables(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(count_variables("Test"), 0)

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(count_variables("Test {0} {1}"), 2)

    def test_3(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            count_variables("Test {0} {2}")

    def test_4(self):
        self.assertEqual(count_variables("Test {} {}"), 2)

    def test_5(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            count_variables("Test{ {} {}")

    def test_6(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            count_variables("Test {} {0}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Output**

```
......
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: Sorry, but I did not want to use regex for this method. Thank for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `string.Format` object and use its `parse` method to break the string into `(literal_text, field_name, format_spec, conversion)` tuples. This will catch some errors such as the unescaped `{` but others, such as improperly numbered fields, won't be caught.

As a gut feeling, I think you could create a child of `string.Format` that returns mock data for its various calls, recoding details as it goes. You'd then catch all of the errors. That should be easier than figuring it out yourself.

As far as getting counts and catching some format errors, this will do:

```
import string

def count_variables(fmtstr):
    parser = string.Formatter().parse(fmtstr)
    items = []
    while True:
        try:
            item = next(parser)
            items.append(item)
            literal_text, field_name, format_spec, conversion = item
            # analyze here...
        except ValueError as e:
            retval = e
            break
        except StopIteration:
            retval = len(items)
            break
    print fmtstr + ':', retval
    return retval
```

Comment: It was a good start by using string.Formatter(). Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41619738/1066801) and to handle the following case:

```
vcount("Test {0} {1} {0} ") # -> 3 (Should be 2)
```

I suggest this solution based on @VPfB answer

```
def count_and_check_fields(string_format):
    try:
        unnamed_fields_count = 0
        named_fields = set()
        for literal_text, field_name, format_spec, conversion in string.Formatter().parse(string_format):
            if field_name is not None:
                if field_name:
                    named_fields.add(field_name)
                else:
                    unnamed_fields_count += 1

        fields_count = len(named_fields) + unnamed_fields_count
        string_format.format(*range(fields_count))

        return fields_count, None
    except Exception as err:
        return None, err.message

count_and_check_fields("Test {0} {1} {0} ") # -> 2
count_and_check_fields("Test {} {} {} ") # -> 3
```